# AListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, events

```
public class AListener implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3;

    public AListener (JTextField tf1, JTextField tf2, JTextField tf3){
        this.tf1= tf1;
        this.tf2=tf2;
        this.tf3=tf3;
    }

    public void actionperformed(ActionEvent e){
        float number1= Float.parseFloat(tf1.getText());
        float number2= Float.parseFloat(tf2.getText());
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ADD")){
            tf3.setText(number1+number2+"");
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("SUBTRACT")){
        tf3.setActionCommand(number1-number2+"");}
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("MULTIPLY")){
        tf3.setActionCommand(number1*number2+"");}
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Divide")){
        tf3.setActionCommand(number1/number2+"");}          
        }         
    }
```

//AListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener????

Comment: What exactly is your question

Comment: rename `actionperformed` to `actionPerformed`

Comment: Unrelated: that is why you receive feedback. And hint: the idea is not to ask things here that you can *easily* figure yourself. In other words: it is not helpful in the long run to train yourself to turn to SO in order to *translate* compiler messages to you. You should understand that each and any character that you put down in your source code has *meaning*. You have to be careful about such details. And you should try to **search** for your error messages first. Putting up such questions is simply a big detour for you.

Comment: @GhostCat tried to delete it before you do, just didn’t know how

Comment: As said, that is why I am giving feedback. Put up good content, and the upvotes will be with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
actionperformed
```

should be

```
actionPerformed
```

You can easily test this by adding the `@Override` annotation.